# SharePoint2013 create calculated column

Tags: sharepoint-online, column, calculated-column

Trying to create a calculated column in a List in SharePoint2013 Online based on 2 other columns that get values from another Lookup table(having a text column). So now my List looks:

- Title    Planned   Original    Difference
- Proj1   2016W52       2016W51        1
- Proj2   2017W1        2017W4        -3
- Proj3   2016W52       2017W1        -1

The Difference = PlannedWeek- OriginalWeek. What formula could i apply to the calculated column in such a scenario.

Answer (score 3):

SharePoint doesn't allow Lookup column to be part of the Calculated Column formula . so you can't directly do this, instead you can create a List Workflow using SharePoint designer which will run when an item is changed or created and update the lookup column value to another custom column.

and this custom column can be used in the calculated columns formula.

here whenever the value in the lookup list for that column changes it doesn't get updated to the custom column. it needs to be taken care.

Comment: Thanks Esaki. I am quiet new to workflows. Could you tell me how to built that step by step.

Comment: A simple workflow to achieve this can be developed from SharePoint Designer please refer for the steps : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj554671.aspx